# Close connection & unload userform

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have the below code which used to insert data in SQLite database. The code is working as expected during import data.

However, the `Finally` part generates an error of `Cannot access a disposed object.` at line `SQLiteConnection.Close()`

What I m trying to do is to close connection and unload form at the final part regardless if the record imported or there is an error.

```
Private SQLitecnStr As String = "Data Source=XXXXXXX; Integrated Security=true"
Private SQLiteConnection As New SQLiteConnection(SQLitecnStr)
Private SQLiteCommand As New SQLiteCommand(SQLiteConnection)

Public Sub ExecuteNonQuery(SQLQuery As String, TargetForm As Form)

    Try

        Using SQLiteConnection
            Using SQLiteCommand
                SQLiteConnection.Open()
                SQLiteCommand.CommandText = SQLQuery
                SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & vbNewLine & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Warning")
    Finally
        SQLiteConnection.Close()
        TargetForm.Close()
    End Try
    
End Sub
```

Jimi suggestion:

```
Public Sub ExecuteNonQuery(SQLQuery As String, NotificationOnSuccess As String, NotificationOnError As String, TargetForm As Form)

    Try

        Using SQLiteConnection As New SQLiteConnection(SQLitecnStr)
            Using SQLiteCommand As New SQLiteCommand(SQLiteConnection)
                SQLiteConnection.Open()
                SQLiteCommand.CommandText = SQLQuery
                SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using

        MsgBox(NotificationOnSuccess, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Record Succesfully Added")

    Catch SQLiteException As Exception
        'Check If The Company Already Exists
        If SQLiteException.Message.Contains("UNIQUE") Then
            MsgBox(NotificationOnError, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Record Already Exists")
        Else
            MsgBox("Error: " & vbNewLine & SQLiteException.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Warning")
        End If
    Finally
        TargetForm.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You have `Using SQLiteConnection`: when that `Using` block exits, it disposes the connection. You don't need to close it again in the `Finally` block, it's already closed (and disposed) -- BTW, what's the point of having a Connection object declared as a Field, when you dispose of it after use? Declare it in-place, drop the Fiels. Same for the DbCommand

Comment: @Jimi could you please have a look at the edited question confirm that this is what do you mean with your comment?

Comment: Pretty much. You should evaluate what  `SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns (rows actually affected by the command)

Comment: @Jimi thanks a lot for your help. how can i evaluated the result of the query? i m new in vb.net and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's in the documentation for the command.... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand.executenonquery?view=msdata-sqlite-6.0.0 (look at "Returns" )

Comment: According to [using statement - ensure the correct use of disposable objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using): _When the control leaves the block of the using statement, an acquired IDisposable instance is disposed. In particular, the using statement ensures that a disposable instance is disposed even if an exception occurs within the block of the using statement._

Comment: The following may be of interest: [SqlCommand constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#overloads).

Comment: Think you might want to read up a little on [ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand.executenonquery?view=msdata-sqlite-6.0.0).  That returns the number of records affected, normally used for Update/Insert operations, If your looking for a query result set possibly [ExecuteReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand.executereader?view=msdata-sqlite-6.0.0) is more what your after